# Difference between binding and with-bindings

Tags: multithreading, syntax, clojure

What is the difference between the Clojure functions `binding` and `with-bindings`? They seem to do the exact same thing but with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with-bindings is useful when you need to **dynamically choose what to bind**. here's a fun example where we randomly choose what to bind:

```
user> (def ^:dynamic a)
#'user/a
user> (def ^:dynamic b)
#'user/b
user> (binding [a 1
                b 2]
        (+ a b))
3
user> (with-bindings (if (rand-nth [true false])
                       {#'a 1
                        #'b (rand-int 10)}
                       {#'a 1
                        #'b 2})
        (+ a b))
3
user> (with-bindings (if (rand-nth [true false])
                       {#'a 1
                        #'b (rand-int 10)}
                       {#'a 1
                        #'b 2})
        (+ a b))
3
user> (with-bindings (if (rand-nth [true false])
                       {#'a 1
                        #'b (rand-int 10)}
                       {#'a 1
                        #'b 2})
        (+ a b))
1
```

if you try that with `bind` it will be upset about not being passed a literal vector as the binding form.

```
user> (binding (if (rand-nth [true false])
                 {#'a 1
                  #'b (rand-int 10)}
                 {#'a 1
                  #'b 2})
        (+ a b))
IllegalArgumentException binding requires a vector for its binding in user:138  clojure.core/binding (core.clj:1865)
```

Comment: Thanks! It confused me that the docs for [`binding`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding) do not mention threads while the docs for [`with-bindings`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-bindings) do. But your example is very clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does the same thing:

```
(def ^:dynamic x 1)
;;=> #'user/x

x
;;=> 1

(with-bindings {#'x 2}
   x)
;;=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may notice a small difference in input parameters: `binding` takes symbols whereas `with-bindings` accepts variables. Also, as it was said above, since `with-bindings` takes a map, you may compose it dynamically depending on your application logic.